# When constructing a tibble with `tribble()`, how to (rowwise) pass value from one column to another?

Tags: r, tibble

I'm constructing a tibble using `tribble()`, with one character column and and one list-column that holds functions inside.

I'm trying to have the functions read from the character column:

```r
library(tibble)

my_trib <-
tibble::tribble(
   ~var,      ~my_func,
  "ABC",      ~tolower(var),
  "abc",      ~toupper(var)
  )
```

I *expected* to get:

```r
my_trib$my_func
# [[1]]
# ~tolower("ABC")

# [[2]]
# ~toupper("abc")
```

But in reality got:

```r
my_trib$my_func
#> [[1]]
#> ~tolower(var)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> ~toupper(var)
```

Is there a way to utilize `tibble::tribble()` to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unlike `tibble()`, `tribble()` doesn't support this behaviour:

```
# With `tribble()`:
tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  1 ,  x
)
#> Error in list2(...) : object 'x' not found

# With `tibble()`:
tibble(
  x = 1,
  y = x
)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
```

Your best bet is probably to simply define `var` outside the call and reference each element inside `tribble()`:

```
library(tibble)

var <- c("ABC", "abc")

my_trib <- tibble::tribble(
    ~var, ~my_func,
  var[1], ~tolower(var[1]),
  var[2], ~toupper(var[2])
)

my_trib$my_func
#> [[1]]
#> ~tolower(var[1])
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> ~toupper(var[2])
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but then the readability (which is why I use `tribble()`) is gone. Bummer.

Comment: Ikr. I think if I was gonna do something like this, I'd first create a column for `var` and then use `mutate()` and `case_when()` to create the column `my_func`. More long-winded, but I think more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a column with plain functions, you can use `rowwise()` and `mutate()` (or `mutate(map(...))` :

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~var,      ~my_func,
  "ABC",     tolower,
  "abc",     toupper
) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(my_val = my_func(var)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   var   my_func my_val
#>   <chr> <list>  <chr> 
#> 1 ABC   <fn>    abc   
#> 2 abc   <fn>    ABC
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>